# How to deploy Kibana4 in tomcat?

Tags: kibana

As mentioned in title ...
regarding kibana3 or previous version we can deploy it in tomcat (just copy kibana folder to webapp folder of tomcat) ,now how to do it with kibana4 ?

actually ,i know i can use kibana4 just by runing kibana.bat file which resides in bin folder ,but i dont want to use it in this way according to our requirement .so just ignore this way .

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6):

Kibana 4 requires use of its own app-server to run for some advanced features that can't be implemented in pure JS:

**rashidkpc**:

> The integrated web server will become a required part of Kibana 4 as
>   we move towards implementing features that can not be fully realized
>   in javascript, for this reason we do not support separating the
>   frontend from the new backend for the purpose of running on a 3rd
>   party web server.

**spenceralger**:

> Using your server as a reverse proxy that transmits requests back to
>   Kibana shouldn't be hard with most modern servers.

You can find additional information on GitHub:

- [How to deploy Kibana4 in tomcat?](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1687)
- [Kibana 4 package as static html/js](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1628)

Issue 1628 contains some hacks on how to run current version of Kibana 4 as a static web app.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have improved my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate repository for a static version of Kibana 4.

Here's the link to the basic release: https://github.com/kibana-community/kibana4-static/releases/tag/v4.0.1-static

Here's the link to the release that includes a workaround for an issue with requests with the rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: false setting: https://github.com/kibana-community/kibana4-static/releases/tag/v4.0.1-static-disallow_explicit_index